# File Write Thread safe C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I am getting error for the below code 
I am implementing thread safe write to files as below ::
This is for only learning purpose, i am adding more text because stack overflow wants me to overflow the text.

```
class OpenFile
{
    string fileName;
    static map<string, unique_ptr<mutex>> fmap;
    bool flag;
public :
    OpenFile(string file) : fileName(file) {
        try {
            if(checkFile(file))
            {
                flag = false;
                fmap.emplace(file, make_unique<mutex>());
            }
            else
            {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        catch(string str)
        {
            cout << str << endl;
        }
    }
    void writeToFile(const string& str) const
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lck(*fmap.find(fileName)->second);
            ofstream ofile(fileName, ios::app);
            ofile << "Writing to the file " << str << endl;
            ofile.close();
        }
        else
        {
            ofstream ofile(fileName, ios::app);
            ofile << "Writing to the file " << str << endl;
            ofile.close();
        }
    }
    string ReadFile() const
    {
        string line;
        if (flag)
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lck(*fmap.find(fileName)->second);
            ifstream ifile(fileName, ios::in);
            getline(ifile, line);
            ifile.close();
        }
        else
        {
            ifstream ifile(fileName, ios::in);
            getline(ifile, line);
            ifile.close();
        }
        return line;
    }
    OpenFile() = delete;
    OpenFile& operator=(const OpenFile& o) = delete;
    static bool checkFile(string& fname);
};


bool OpenFile::checkFile(string& fname)
{
    if (fmap.find(fname)==fmap.end())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Initial error was because of not passing data by ref to thread.. 
Error from VS2015 ::

```
Description Project Line    Suppression State
'bool OpenFile::checkFile::<lambda_2bd4a02838a970867505463f4b7b6b9e>::operator ()(const std::pair<std::string,std::unique_ptr<std::mutex,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>' to 'const std::pair<std::string,std::unique_ptr<std::mutex,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>'  BoQian  43
```

I think i have fixed it now, thank you

Comment: `unique_ptr<mutex>` in the pair is not copyable, remember?

Comment: if (find_if(fmap.begin(), fmap.end(), [&fname](auto& m)

Comment: I am in learning mode, i am being explicit but im learning so much in such short time it getting over my head. And my gf is really messing things up :P. I see it now Thank you

Comment: Any suggestions in making it faster? I realized some time synchronization would help in reducing multiple file open closes. Like put the data in buffer and write after it hits some size. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to use `find_if` at all in your `checkFile` function.

This is how you should do:

```
bool OpenFile::checkFile(string& fname)
{
    return fmap.find(fname) != fmap.end();
}
```